# xcode 8+ current location swift

Tags: location, swift3, mapkit

This is my button click code

```
@IBAction func loc_btn_actn(_ sender: Any) {

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    shyMap.showsUserLocation = true

}
```

this is my locationManager function

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let userLocation:CLLocation = locations[0] as CLLocation

    manager.stopUpdatingLocation()

    let coordinations = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: userLocation.coordinate.latitude,longitude: userLocation.coordinate.longitude)
    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.2,0.2)
    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinations, span: span)

    shyMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)

}
```

when i am clicking button i am getting app delegate error cant able to track location

Comment: I wonder, though, about whether you instantiated the `CLLocationManager` correctly. Can you show us that?

Comment: ya thats I am declaring wrong it's done 
now how can i get latitude and longitude thorough 
userLocation.coordinate.latitude . ??

Comment: BTW, you can simplify `coordinations` to simply `let coordinations = userLocation.coordinate`. Why build a new `CLLocationCoordinate2D` from the `latitude` and `longitude` of `userLocation.coordinate` when that's already a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`?

Comment: "now how can i get latitude and longitude?" ... I'm not following you. If your `didUpdateLocations` was called, you have it already. Can you clarify what you mean?

Comment: If you're not seeing `didUpdateLocations` being called, did you set `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription` entry in your `Info.plist`? See the [`requestWhenInUseAuthorization` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620562-requestwheninuseauthorization).